# Reading/Writing wrapped text in Fortran

Tags: fortran90, fortran95

What's the best way to read and write vector data (1 dimension) that has been wrapped to a specified number of columns (10 columns in this example).

```
integer : data(100)

DATA (node)
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
20 21 23 34 35 31 91 32 31 34
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 34 31 34
```

I basically want to read in this data and maintain it as a 1D vector. And Vice Versa (i.e. write data out in a wrapped format. Cheers. Neil

Comment: Also, do you want to read in rows or in columns?

Comment: I tried many combinations of read statements - I want to in read in column order.. Figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: Its basically just a read statement in a column loop

```
read(7,*)(data(node),node=1,maxnodes)
```

and to write it:

```
write(7,10i10)(data(node),node=1,maxnodes)
```

Comment: Well done !  You have justified my decision not to spoon-feed you an answer. I suggest that you re-edit your question to remove the now redundant 'answer' it contains.